# What are the requirements for a portal from a portal gun (in Portal/Portal 2) to form?

Tags: portal, portal-2

I was under the impression from some of the quotes in Portal 2 that the portal gun only worked on surfaces painted with moon-dust paint, or other moon-related surfaces. However browsing through Portal 2 quotations, I'm not sure that moon-related surfaces are technically a requirement. I can't recall/find any in-game references to prove or strike down this point.

So: is lunar material a requirement for the surface when forming portals produced by the portal gun found in Portal/Portal 2?

Comment: Are you asking about gameplay, or game story? We handle the backstory for games, but [Arqade](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/) handles gameplay mechanics.

Comment: This is 100% a story question, not gameplay. I'm wondering this as an in-universe question, @phantom42.

Comment: Cool. Your half-life tags threw me as I haven't played those games yet.

Comment: The requirements were: 1 - solid surface, 2 - porous surface.  So drywall and concrete were easy.  Metal sheets were not.  Moon dust gel was a great conductor, that's why it still worked after being a liquid sloshed all over.  Unfortunately, I can't find reference for any of this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My impression is that other materials also worked. There's a brief extro in Portal 2 where Cave speaks about his experimentation with Moon Dust:

> "The bean counters told me we literally could not afford to buy seven
>   dollars worth of moon rocks, much less seventy million. Bought 'em
>   anyway. Ground 'em up, mixed em into a gel."
>
> "And guess what? Ground up moon rocks are pure poison. I am deathly
>   ill."
>
> "Still, it turns out they're a great portal conductor. So now we're
>   gonna see if jumping in and out of these new portals can somehow leech
>   the lunar poison out of a man's bloodstream. When life gives you
>   lemons, make lemonade. [coughs] Let's all stay positive and do some
>   science."

The implication is that if there are *new portals* (e.g. where moon dust is used as the conductor) there must have been *old portals* where it was not.

---

And to quote directly from the [developer's website](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Portal_Mapping_FAQ#How_do_I_let_people_place_portals_on_concrete_next_to_metal_surfaces.3F):

> **How do I let people place portals *on concrete* next to metal surfaces?**
>
> *Any place where a concrete surface is flush with a metal surface, create a func_portal_bumper brush entity 32 units wide next to the
>   concrete and over the metal.*

Obviously this doesn't preclude the concrete being made *from* moon rocks, but it seems unlikely.

Comment: Poor Cave Johnson.  His story always made me sad.

Comment: Speculation: Regolith (ok... Moon Dust) is primarily a fine silica powder with a bit of added iron.  Breathing in respirable silica like this causes the fatal disease silicosis. One major outward symptom is coughing.  There is no cure so I imagine he would look for a longshot one. SiO2 is also pretty much just crushed quartz, granite, or most anything else which is used as a filler for concrete (most I said).

Answer (score 7):

Moon rock can't have been required, because Aperture built the first Aperture Science Portable Quantum Tunneling Devices in the 1950s, before moon rock was available.

I think this image is not canonical, but the small graphic in its lower right corner is based on ones that appear in the game (see 2nd picture).

[image]

This image appears in the 1950s area of the game.

[image]

Comment: For the record, it's possible to collect moon rock from places like Antarctica, ejected from the moon in impacts.

Comment: Also, in the universe of *Portal*, people went to space at least a decade earlier than an our universe.

Comment: @RogueJedi Interesting! I've only played the game, don't know any of the extra material.  Where is this early lunar landing described?

Comment: @OrganicMarble It's in-game. In our world, man first went to space in 1961. However, in *Portal 2*, the 1950's area of Aperture mentions astronauts performing test.

Comment: @RogueJedi the first NASA astronaut class was selected in 1959.

Comment: @OrganicMarble In *Portal 2*, astronauts are already famous. So if they had only been selected less than a year ago, and had yet to go to space, that wouldn't make sense.